# parse response received from rememberCustomViewAsync from tableau javascript api

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to save custom views using `rememberCustomViewAsync` and displaying the saved view using `showCustomViewAsync`, I want to parse the response received from executing `rememberCustomViewAsync`, it returns various details including the `url` of the view.

here is the code i am trying

```
        $(document).on('click', '.new_dashboard_preference > [type="button"]', function() {
          tableauViz.getWorkbook().rememberCustomViewAsync($('#dashboard_preference_name').val()).then(function(customView) {
            console.log(customView.url); //this is what i am trying to access
            jQuery(this).parent('form')[0].submit();
          }).otherwise(function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
          });

        });
```

Can any please guide as to how the response received from `rememberCustomViewAsync` be parsed in javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a JSON object you can use:

responseVariable = JSON.parse(responseVariable)

You can then use accessors like responseVariable.ItemYouWantToSee or array index accessors such as responseVariable[0].

To take this out of the 'click' event listener and make it a global object you can push the result to an array.